# Qual a função sintática da locução "ou seja" na frase "Estou com problemas de saúde e resolvi parar de fumar, ou seja, mudar de vida."

Tags: análise-sintática

Qual a função sintática da locução "ou seja" na frase:

*"Estou com problemas de saúde e resolvi parar de fumar, ou seja, mudar de vida."*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ela *liga*, *conecta* duas orações *independentes*, em que uma delas *explica* algo da outra oração: portanto, "ou seja" é uma locução **conjuntiva coordenativa explicativa** (se se tratasse de uma só palavra, seria uma *conjunção* ao invés de "locução conjuntiva").

Fontes:

- https://www.normaculta.com.br/conjuncoes-explicativas/
- http://canalinteligente.com/o-correto-uso-do-ou-seja/
- https://www.todamateria.com.br/locucao-conjuntiva/

Comment: Ótimo @stafusa. Obrigado.